# (Makefile error: *** missing separator) The following makefile works fine in my local IDEs but fails when i run in the Putty client

Tags: makefile

Makefile fails due to missing separator error on Putty client.

I've tried remaking the file and replacing every space by a tab but nothing seems to works

```
CLIENT         = IntegerStackTest
ADT            = IntegerStack
SOURCE         = $(CLIENT).c
OBJECT         = $(CLIENT).o
ADT_SOURCE     = $(ADT).c
ADT_OBJECT     = $(ADT).o
ADT_HEADER     = $(ADT).h
COMPILE        = gcc -c -std=c99 -Wall
LINK           = gcc -o
REMOVE         = rm -f
MEMCHECK       = valgrind --leak-check=full

$(CLIENT) : $(OBJECT) $(ADT_OBJECT)
    $(LINK) $(CLIENT) $(OBJECT) $(ADT_OBJECT)

$(OBJECT) : $(SOURCE) $(ADT_HEADER)
    $(COMPILE) $(SOURCE)

$(ADT_OBJECT) : $(ADT_SOURCE) $(ADT_HEADER)
    $(COMPILE) $(ADT_SOURCE)

clean :
    $(REMOVE) $(CLIENT) $(OBJECT) $(ADT_OBJECT)

memcheck : $(CLIENT)
    $(MEMCHECK) $(CLIENT)
```

Makefile:1: *** missing separator.  Stop.

Comment: Using space indentation instead of tab indentation is the most common cause of that problem, but second most common these days is probably having foreign line terminators in the Makefile (generally Windows line terminators when `make` is running on Linux or Mac).  If you have the `dos2unix` utility available to you, then running the makefile through that might help.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is relevant, but I assume you are using PuTTy for your makefile to build the code on a machine running across an IP Network of (ssh) or across an RS232 Serial Link.

If that is the case, then the only problem that could occur would be due to

1. The target host being different from the development station on which you use your IDE. There are some anomalies between different controllers and/or different OS or RTOS version running on the host.
2. It could be (though remotely) possible due to the terminal encoding settings if it is a serial link that you are building on. (CR/LF/CRLF for Line ends etc)

You might just try to use an emulator for the target platform, build the binary and then upload the binary instead of compiling on the target.

I stumbled across some of these irritants working with MicroC OS on Rabbit Platform.

All the best man. I am kinda new here. Dunno if this helps ?

Best of Luck, mate.